# CSV Import in SilverStripe Duplicates and RelationCallbacks

Tags: php, csv, silverstripe

I need to understand the code below, specially how exactly `$duplicateChecks` and `$relationCallbacks` work but there is little explanation on the official documentation. Can somebody explain how these work or suggest some other documentation I can look at?

```php
class PlayerCsvBulkLoader extends CsvBulkLoader {
   public $columnMap = array(
      'Number' => 'PlayerNumber', 
      'Name' => '->importFirstAndLastName', 
      'Birthday' => 'Birthday', 
      'Team' => 'Team.Title', 
   );
   public $duplicateChecks = array(
      'Number' => 'PlayerNumber'
   );
   public $relationCallbacks = array(
      'Team.Title' => array(
         'relationname' => 'Team',
         'callback' => 'getTeamByTitle'
      )
   );
   public static function importFirstAndLastName(&$obj, $val, $record) {
      $parts = explode(' ', $val);
      if(count($parts) != 2) return false;
      $obj->FirstName = $parts[0];
      $obj->LastName = $parts[1];
   }
   public static function getTeamByTitle(&$obj, $val, $record) {
      return FootballTeam::get()->filter('Title', $val)->First();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$duplicateChecks` is used by [`findExistingObject`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-CsvBulkLoader.html#205-243) function in the [`CsvBulkLoader`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-CsvBulkLoader.html) class. It is iterated over to find any object that has a column with the specified value. In that example, it checks the "PlayerNumber" column.

It can also be passed a callback like so:

```
public $duplicateCheck = array(
    'Number' => array(
        'callback' => 'checkPlayerNumberFunction'
    )
);
```

The callback specified needs to either exist on an instance of the class specified on the property `objectClass` or on the `CsvBulkLoader` itself (which would happen if you extended it). These callbacks are used to do more complex duplicate lookups and return an existing object (if any) found.

`$relationCallbacks` on the other hand is used by the main [`processRecord`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-CsvBulkLoader.html#98-195) function. The callback works in the same way as the `$duplicateCheck` callback, it needs to either exist on an instance of the class specified on the proeprty `objectClass` or on the `CsvBulkLoader`. These callbacks can return an object that will be related back to a specific object record (new or existing) as a `has_one`.

There is a little more to it than that though the best way to learn is by a bit of experimentation and jumping through the code of the class itself. I have linked to the various functions etc in my answer.